# Weird sudo behavior on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, administrator, sudo

I have a company MacBook Pro. I am sudoer and I can do anything that requires admin privileges when I'm connected to the company network. But I can't when I'm home. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

This special behavior is probably related to the *sudoers* file.

By modifying this file in /private/etc/ one can restrict the sudoers to particular networks or single IP-addresses:

The common user privileges specs are as following:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
        |    |    |command
        |    |as user
        | hosts
```

This means: the users of the group *admin* can sudo any command as any user ("Runas") from all networks.

By specifying a restricted host/network in the host alias specification earlier in the same file this may be changed:

```
# Host alias specification

Host_Alias      COMPNET = 172.17.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

Modifying the user privilege specifications to:

```
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  COMPNET=(ALL) ALL
```

doesn't allow you to execute *sudo* in your home network if the IP-address is **not** in the above range (e.g. your home network provides DHCP leases in the 192.168.0.0/24 range and none of the other interfaces have an IP in the above 172.17.0.0/255.255.0.0 network). Back in the company network (e.g. with a DHCP range 172.17.5.0/24) sudoing works again.

Comment: Don't edit it on your own. Set EDITOR and use `visudo` as root.

Comment: I have those privileges and can do sudo now. However, I still cannot install applications the usual way...

Comment: @Bob My answer is just one possible answer. You'd have to add additional informations to your question. How did you get back your `sudo` privileges?

Comment: by adding my name in sudoers under /private

Comment: @Bob can you post the original content of your sudoers flie? Or does it contain any secret data (like company network data, user groups etc.)? You may have to sanitize the file before posting it here!

Comment: @Bob As said your company admins may use other means than the sudoers file to restrict access.